# Link styles and scripts issue with htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<link href="http://example.com/views/cp/css/style.css" />
```

The style not read because of .htaccess RewriteRule change it.
How can i do it with the same .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just avoid rewriting it for real files and directories:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You changed the .htaccess file.

Comment: If one writes a rule that causes 500 then it needs to fixed. This is also faulty rule that required fixing